# <403> Forbidden on the https:// URL, and <302> Moved Temporarily when using the http:// URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Our web authentication platform faced an unexpected behavior couple days ago when a user was unable to connect to our authentication servers, which is actually a method that POSTs data to our URL at `https://xxxxxxxx.com/authentication/authorize.php`. We were unsure what the problem was - our servers? The client they were using? Their firewalls?

This is the method we used through the experimentation below:

```
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false; // false so we don't get redirected

    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int)webResponse.StatusCode);
        headers.Add("Status Desc: " + webResponse.StatusDescription);
        foreach (string key in webResponse.Headers.Keys)
        {
            if (!key.ToString().Equals("Location"))
            {
                var value = webResponse.Headers[key];
                headers.Add(key + ": " + value);
            }
        }
    }
```

We had him send over a header report:

[image]

[image]

It appears we were were `4XX` tier status code errors from this user.

Upon Googling, we found this [article](http://www.techieshelp.com/you-don%E2%80%99t-have-permission-to-access-wp-adminpost-php-on-this-server/) which instructs you to change the `.htacess` files. Specifically, it's an issue where `your website host may be implementing filtering which creates a mod_security error.`

We put this code snippet into our `.htacess`:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
 SecFilterEngine Off
 SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

We ask the user to run our headers script again, and this was returned:

[image]

The `https://` URL still returned a `<403> Forbidden` error, however, the `http://` domain (non-encrypted one) finally gave us a voice. Note, the desired status code is a `302 Found`, as any one that tries to navigate into that URL should be redirected to our host domain. It seems in this issue, we got a `302 Moved Temporarily`.

From our experimentation, it looks like changing `.htaccess` did indeed allow us to make some progress, but not using the `https://` protocol is an issue. We have contacted our server hosts asking for some insight as to why this is happening (such as -- do you guys implement filtering?), and we are currently waiting for a reply.

My question is -- what is going on? Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: It may be worthwhile removing this question, and asking again depending upon the answer you receive about HTTPS filtering. That alone is such a significant detail that a decent answer cannot be given until that is known.

Comment: User @Sam Goldberg seems to provide some insight into my issue. Perhaps this user is using our application under a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you are getting back "Proxy Authentication Required" looks like the user is going through a proxy server to get to the web.  First thing to check is that the browser or app user is using to get to your site is correctly connecting and authenticating to his proxy server.  The next thing to check is whether their proxy admin has somehow blocked access to your URL (less likely).  Maybe you can update your tester app to print the IP address of the server which responded, chances are it will be the address of a proxy server, and not your server.

Comment: That's a very very good point that I didn't address. Our user is happy to help us -- do you suggest us to talk to their IT department to see if it an issue on their end with the proxy server they use?

Comment: Hi Sam, how does the IP address indicate that the person is in a proxy server or not?

Comment: Also -- what is the purpose of using a proxy server [in a company] to communicate to the internet anyways? Like a sort of firewall, monitoring, or access restrictions?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean right now about the IP address. Matching the IP address of our URL versus the one that this user is communicating it will allow us to determine whether or not the user is connecting to *our* server versus *something* else.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Proxy server is very standard in large companies. They use it to filter users' access to the internet. (For example, they don't want them to use online chat sites, or block Facebook, etc.)  So it is very typical to find an internet proxy used in a large company.

Comment: Hi Sam. Interesting development. We gave them the host, so `https://xxxxxx.com/`, and their reply was "if you could supply the exact websites (exact URL) that would be very helpful. The proxy blocks the software from the initial registration (where you enter your email to receive authentication code) to actually using the software in action (where it access the various external datasets)." Realistically wouldn't giving just the domain be more than enough? You could set `https://xxxxxx.com/*` to white list all sites. But according to their firewall, it's not specific enough?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: perhaps they would be satisfied if you just give them a root url, e.g.  https://ourdomain.com/ourapp.  Probably they don't want to whitelist a whole domain for security reasons.  A conversation with the proxy security team would probably enlighten you, more than I can.